# Cannot boot Ubuntu from GRUB2 console after installing Qubes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a brand new laptop that came with Windows pre-installed. I managed to install Ubuntu 22.04 as dual boot which worked very well. I then added Qubes OS to the mix. Unfortunately I messed something up in the installation and Qubes seems to have killed my ability to boot into Linux/Windows and even manually booting from the GRUB2 console fails. Ubuntu & Windows do not show up as options in the boot menu anymore.

Note that I did check the partition contents of both Ubuntu and Windows to be intact from the looks of it (mounting them inside Qubes and `ls`-ing around).

Here's how I manually attempted booting Ubuntu from the GRUB2 console:
[image]

Not also how tab-completion works, so the partition seems to be there. Also booting seems to start well but then hangs for a long time (a few minutes) at this point:
[image]

It then eventually fails a little bit later with the following output:
[image]

I then check the `journalctl -xb` output which is very long and ends like this:
[image]

Any pointers on what to check or how to fix/boot my Ubuntu would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather annoying, I had accidentally overwritten my EFI partition and reinstalled all 3 OSs again and this time made sure that each of them has their own EFI partition.